# ubuntu linux install homestead conflict apache

Tags: apache, laravel, ubuntu

Laravel Homestead has a conflict with Apache server.

I installed Laravel Homestead on a Linux Ubuntu 15.04 virtual machine.  The Ubuntu distribution comes with Apache already installed.  The result is that when I try to load the "homestead.app" page in a browser, the Apache server returns the default page assigned by Apache server.

Please, how to I resolve this conflict, so that attempting to load "homestead.app" in a browser will return the default page for Laravel Homestead, instead of the Apache page?

Comment: This sounds as if you have an issue with your networking setup, since apparently the requests do not reach the virtual box, but the hosts server. This _might_ be because the virtual box fails to bind to the http port, since the apache http server is blocking that. Why don't you remove the apache http server or at least deactivate it?

Comment: One other question: why do you install a virtual appliance (so a virtual machine) on top of another virtual machine? The idea behind the Laravel approach is to give you a virtual machine that you install on your normal system, not inside another virtual machine. That would only make things more complex. So why?

Comment: Sounds odd to require two levels of virtualization, doesn't it?  I previously installed Laravel Homestead directly on the Windows host environment.  The Laravel documentation treats Windows as a special case (read "problem child").  After a series of seemingly endless conflicts between Homestead and the Windows host, I tried installing Laravel Homestead on a Ubuntu virtual machine.

Comment: Could you please point out where in the [Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead) is Homestead on Windows treated as a _special case_? Because there's a note on the need to enable hardware virtualization on Windows? (that's not something specific to Homestead). Having 2 levels of virtualization will probably give you more headaches than trying to make it work with Windows. And on that point, what were the issues that you were having when Windows was the host?